# Added UIBarButtonItem cannot be triggered

Tags: ios, swift, webview

language: `swift 3.0`

os: `macOS 10.12.3`

xcode: `8.2.1`

Here is a blank Storyboard with a ViewController.

And below is the code:

```
import UIKit
import WebKit

class CommonWebViewViewController: UIViewController, WKUIDelegate, WKNavigationDelegate {

    let backButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "BACK", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(goBack))
    let closeButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "CLOSE", style: .plain, target: nil, action: #selector(close))

    let webview = WKWebView()
    var url = ""

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view = webview

        navigationItem.setLeftBarButtonItems([backButton], animated: true)

        webview.uiDelegate = self
        webview.navigationDelegate = self
        webview.allowsBackForwardNavigationGestures = true
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
        title = webView.title
    }

    func load(withUrl url: String) {
        self.url = url
        webview.load(URLRequest(url: URL(string: self.url)!))
    }

    func goBack() {
        if webview.canGoBack {
            webview.goBack()
            navigationItem.leftBarButtonItems?.append(closeButton)
        }
        else {
            close()
        }
    }

    func close() {
        _ = self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
    }

}
```

I want to make a browser, and when I tap the BACK button, there's no response unless I click a link in webview.

P.S if I create the UIBarButtonItem object in viewDidload method, the problem will be solved.

Comment: You don't seem to add the button to your view at all, how have you "added" them?

Comment: By this line: navigationItem.setLeftBarButtonItems([backButton], animated: true)

Comment: sorry, didn't see it